# android studio doesn't start on mac

Tags: android-studio

I installed Android Studio, but it doesn't run normally.

OS: macos Big Sur 11.1 (20C69)
android studio version: android-studio-ide-201.6953283-mac
java version: 1.8

```
~ java -version
java version "1.8.0_231"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_231-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.231-b11, mixed mode)
```

When I ran it with a double click, it stopped loading as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: android studio launch logo]

So I tried running it in cli. The program was run but some error logs:

```
~ sudo /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio
Password:
2021-01-02 14:28:27.213 studio[24845:598977] allVms required 1.8*,1.8+
2021-01-02 14:28:27.214 studio[24845:598977] Can't find bundled java.The folder doesn't exist: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr
2021-01-02 14:28:27.214 studio[24845:598977] Can't find bundled java.The folder doesn't exist: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jdk
2021-01-02 14:28:27.234 studio[24845:598986] WorkingDirectory is absent in Info.plist. Current Directory: /Users/centell
2021-01-02 14:28:27.234 studio[24845:598986] fullFileName is: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions
2021-01-02 14:28:27.234 studio[24845:598986] fullFileName exists: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions
2021-01-02 14:28:27.234 studio[24845:598986] Value of STUDIO_VM_OPTIONS is (null)
2021-01-02 14:28:27.234 studio[24845:598986] Processing VMOptions file at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions
2021-01-02 14:28:27.235 studio[24845:598986] Done
2021-01-02 14:28:27.235 studio[24845:598986] Processing VMOptions file at /var/root/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/studio.vmoptions
2021-01-02 14:28:27.237 studio[24845:598986] Done
2021-01-02 14:28:27.237 studio[24845:598986] Processing VMOptions file at 
2021-01-02 14:28:27.241 studio[24845:598986] No content found
2021-01-02 14:28:32,835 [   3815]   WARN - Container.ComponentManagerImpl - Do not use constructor injection (requestorClass=com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator) 
2021-01-02 14:28:35,525 [   6505]   WARN - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - keymap "Xcode" not found [Plugin: com.intellij] 
2021-01-02 14:28:35,746 [   6726]   WARN - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - keymap "ReSharper" not found [Plugin: com.android.tools.ndk] 
2021-01-02 14:28:35,966 [   6946]   WARN - nsions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl - Extension to be removed not found: class org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.execution.test.runner.TestClassGradleConfigurationProducer 
2021-01-02 14:28:37,602 [   8582]   WARN - Container.ComponentManagerImpl - Do not use constructor injection (requestorClass=org.jetbrains.android.compose.AndroidComposeAutoDocumentation) 
2021-01-02 14:28:37,820 [   8800]   WARN - Container.ComponentManagerImpl - Do not use constructor injection (requestorClass=com.android.tools.idea.apk.ApkProjectComponent) 
2021-01-02 14:28:37,821 [   8801]   WARN - Container.ComponentManagerImpl - Do not use constructor injection (requestorClass=com.android.tools.idea.apk.issues.SetupIssueReporter) 
2021-01-02 14:28:40,418 [  11398]   WARN - Container.ComponentManagerImpl - Do not use constructor injection (requestorClass=com.android.tools.idea.apk.symbols.DebugSymbolNotifications) 
2021-01-02 14:28:43,214 [  14194]   WARN - ugins.textmate.TextMateService - Missing builtin bundles, checked: 
/var/root/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/plugins/textmate/lib/bundles
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/textmate/lib/bundles 
2021-01-02 14:28:45,652 [  16632]   WARN - com.intellij.util.xmlb.Binding - no accessors for class org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.highlighter.KotlinDefaultHighlightingSettingsProvider 
2021-01-02 14:28:46,671 [  17651]   WARN -            #com.android.ddmlib - * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037 
2021-01-02 14:28:46,967 [  17947]   WARN -            #com.android.ddmlib - * daemon started successfully 
2021-01-02 14:28:47,603 [  18583]   WARN - openapi.wm.impl.ToolWindowImpl - ToolWindow icons should be 13x13. Please fix ToolWindow (ID:  Problems View) or icon jar:file:/Applications/Android%20Studio.app/Contents/lib/icons.jar!/general/warning.svg 
2021-01-02 14:28:47,928 [  18908]   WARN - Container.ComponentManagerImpl - Do not use constructor injection (requestorClass=com.android.tools.idea.apk.ApkWritingAccessProvider) 
2021-01-02 14:28:48,778 [  19758]   WARN - Container.ComponentManagerImpl - Do not use constructor injection (requestorClass=com.android.tools.idea.gradle.notification.GeneratedFileNotificationProvider) 
2021-01-02 14:28:48,820 [  19800]   WARN - Container.ComponentManagerImpl - Do not use constructor injection (requestorClass=com.android.tools.idea.apk.editor.notification.ApkReloadNotificationProvider) 
2021-01-02 14:28:52.581 studio[24845:598977] Warning: Expected min height of view: (<NSButtonJAction: 0x7fa1cb28bcd0>) to be less than or equal to 30 but got a height of 32.000000. This error will be logged once per view in violation.
2021-01-02 14:29:05,916 [  36896]  ERROR - ellij.util.text.DateFormatUtil - Unable to load library 'CoreFoundation':
dlopen(libCoreFoundation.dylib, 9): image not found
dlopen(libCoreFoundation.dylib, 9): image not found
Native library (darwin/libCoreFoundation.dylib) not found in resource path (/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/bootstrap.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/extensions.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/util.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/jdom.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/log4j.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/trove4j.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/jna.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar) 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'CoreFoundation':
dlopen(libCoreFoundation.dylib, 9): image not found
dlopen(libCoreFoundation.dylib, 9): image not found
Native library (darwin/libCoreFoundation.dylib) not found in resource path (/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/bootstrap.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/extensions.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/util.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/jdom.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/log4j.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/trove4j.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/jna.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:302)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:455)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:192)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.load(Native.java:596)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.load(Native.java:570)
    at com.intellij.util.text.DateFormatUtil.getMacFormats(DateFormatUtil.java:363)
    at com.intellij.util.text.DateFormatUtil.getDateTimeFormats(DateFormatUtil.java:303)
    at com.intellij.util.text.DateFormatUtil.<clinit>(DateFormatUtil.java:46)
    at com.intellij.ide.fileTemplates.impl.FileTemplateManagerImpl.getDefaultProperties(FileTemplateManagerImpl.java:158)
    at com.intellij.ide.fileTemplates.FileTemplateUtil.templateToRegex(FileTemplateUtil.java:426)
    at com.intellij.ide.fileTemplates.FileTemplateUtil.getTemplatePattern(FileTemplateUtil.java:418)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.defaultFileTemplateUsage.FileHeaderChecker.checkFileHeader(FileHeaderChecker.java:52)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.defaultFileTemplateUsage.DefaultFileTemplateUsageInspection.checkFile(DefaultFileTemplateUsageInspection.java:58)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.AbstractBaseJavaLocalInspectionTool$1.visitFile(AbstractBaseJavaLocalInspectionTool.java:67)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.xml.XmlFileImpl.accept(XmlFileImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionEngine.acceptElements(InspectionEngine.java:69)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionEngine.createVisitorAndAcceptElements(InspectionEngine.java:60)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LocalInspectionsPass.runToolOnElements(LocalInspectionsPass.java:297)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LocalInspectionsPass.lambda$null$3(LocalInspectionsPass.java:266)
    at com.intellij.util.AstLoadingFilter.forceAllowTreeLoading(AstLoadingFilter.java:155)
    at com.intellij.util.AstLoadingFilter.forceAllowTreeLoading(AstLoadingFilter.java:147)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LocalInspectionsPass.lambda$null$4(LocalInspectionsPass.java:265)
    at com.intellij.util.AstLoadingFilter.disallowTreeLoading(AstLoadingFilter.java:126)
    at com.intellij.util.AstLoadingFilter.disallowTreeLoading(AstLoadingFilter.java:115)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LocalInspectionsPass.lambda$visitPriorityElementsAndInit$5(LocalInspectionsPass.java:265)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.ApplierCompleter.execAndForkSubTasks(ApplierCompleter.java:149)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1104)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.ApplierCompleter.lambda$wrapInReadActionAndIndicator$1(ApplierCompleter.java:105)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:627)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:572)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:61)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.ApplierCompleter.wrapInReadActionAndIndicator(ApplierCompleter.java:117)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.ApplierCompleter.lambda$compute$0(ApplierCompleter.java:96)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ReadMostlyRWLock.executeByImpatientReader(ReadMostlyRWLock.java:168)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.executeByImpatientReader(ApplicationImpl.java:168)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.ApplierCompleter.compute(ApplierCompleter.java:96)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.JobLauncherImpl.invokeConcurrentlyUnderProgress(JobLauncherImpl.java:55)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.JobLauncher.invokeConcurrentlyUnderProgress(JobLauncher.java:49)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LocalInspectionsPass.visitPriorityElementsAndInit(LocalInspectionsPass.java:269)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LocalInspectionsPass.inspect(LocalInspectionsPass.java:193)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LocalInspectionsPass.collectInformationWithProgress(LocalInspectionsPass.java:115)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.ProgressableTextEditorHighlightingPass.doCollectInformation(ProgressableTextEditorHighlightingPass.java:84)
    at com.intellij.codeHighlighting.TextEditorHighlightingPass.collectInformation(TextEditorHighlightingPass.java:52)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$null$1(PassExecutorService.java:442)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1109)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$doRun$2(PassExecutorService.java:435)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:627)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:572)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:61)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.doRun(PassExecutorService.java:434)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$run$0(PassExecutorService.java:410)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ReadMostlyRWLock.executeByImpatientReader(ReadMostlyRWLock.java:168)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.executeByImpatientReader(ApplicationImpl.java:168)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.run(PassExecutorService.java:408)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.JobLauncherImpl$VoidForkJoinTask$1.exec(JobLauncherImpl.java:171)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
    Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen(libCoreFoundation.dylib, 9): image not found
        at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:191)
        ... 58 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen(libCoreFoundation.dylib, 9): image not found
        at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:204)
        ... 58 more
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Native library (darwin/libCoreFoundation.dylib) not found in resource path (/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/bootstrap.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/extensions.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/util.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/jdom.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/log4j.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/trove4j.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/jna.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar)
        at com.sun.jna.Native.extractFromResourcePath(Native.java:1095)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:276)
        ... 58 more
2021-01-02 14:29:05,927 [  36907]  ERROR - ellij.util.text.DateFormatUtil - Android Studio 4.1.1  Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.6953283 
2021-01-02 14:29:05,927 [  36907]  ERROR - ellij.util.text.DateFormatUtil - JDK: 1.8.0_242-release; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2021-01-02 14:29:05,927 [  36907]  ERROR - ellij.util.text.DateFormatUtil - OS: Mac OS X 
2021-01-02 14:29:05,928 [  36908]  ERROR - ellij.util.text.DateFormatUtil - Last Action:  
2021-01-02 14:29:24.395 studio[24845:598977] Warning: Expected min height of view: (<NSButtonJAction: 0x7fa1cebf3f70>) to be less than or equal to 30 but got a height of 32.000000. This error will be logged once per view in violation.
2021-01-02 14:29:24.395 studio[24845:598977] Warning: Expected min height of view: (<NSButtonJAction: 0x7fa1cebf56b0>) to be less than or equal to 30 but got a height of 32.000000. This error will be logged once per view in violation.
2021-01-02 14:29:24.396 studio[24845:598977] Warning: Expected min height of view: (<NSButtonJAction: 0x7fa1cebf6a00>) to be less than or equal to 30 but got a height of 32.000000. This error will be logged once per view in violation.
2021-01-02 14:29:24.397 studio[24845:598977] Warning: Expected min height of view: (<NSButtonJAction: 0x7fa1cc67aa30>) to be less than or equal to 30 but got a height of 32.000000. This error will be logged once per view in violation.
2021-01-02 14:29:25.355 studio[24845:598977] Warning: Expected min height of view: (<NSButtonJAction: 0x7fa1cc737760>) to be less than or equal to 30 but got a height of 32.000000. This error will be logged once per view in violation.
2021-01-02 14:29:25.356 studio[24845:598977] Warning: Expected min height of view: (<NSButtonJAction: 0x7fa1cc6e47f0>) to be less than or equal to 30 but got a height of 32.000000. This error will be logged once per view in violation.
2021-01-02 14:29:25.357 studio[24845:598977] Warning: Expected min height of view: (<NSButtonJAction: 0x7fa1cc738d20>) to be less than or equal to 30 but got a height of 32.000000. This error will be logged once per view in violation.
2021-01-02 14:29:25.357 studio[24845:598977] Warning: Expected min height of view: (<NSButtonJAction: 0x7fa1cc73a1b0>) to be less than or equal to 30 but got a height of 32.000000. This error will be logged once per view in violation.
2021-01-02 14:29:25.358 studio[24845:598977] Warning: Expected min height of view: (<NSButtonJAction: 0x7fa1cc73b5c0>) to be less than or equal to 30 but got a height of 32.000000. This error will be logged once per view in violation.
2021-01-02 14:29:25.838 studio[24845:598977] Warning: Expected min height of view: (<NSButtonJAction: 0x7fa1cc197840>) to be less than or equal to 30 but got a height of 32.000000. This error will be logged once per view in violation.
2021-01-02 14:29:25.840 studio[24845:598977] Warning: Expected min height of view: (<NSButtonJAction: 0x7fa1cc1987f0>) to be less than or equal to 30 but got a height of 32.000000. This error will be logged once per view in violation.
2021-01-02 14:29:28,238 [  59218]   WARN - com.intellij.util.xmlb.Binding - no accessors for class org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.scripting.gradle.GradleScriptInputsWatcher$Storage 
2021-01-02 14:29:28,258 [  59238]   WARN - com.intellij.util.xmlb.Binding - no accessors for class org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.core.script.configuration.utils.ScriptClassRootsStorage
```

How do I run Android Studio normally?

Comment: I am still facing the same issue. So I installed IntelliJ IDEA and Android development with it.

Answer (score 1):

Your log tells the error:

```
2021-01-02 14:28:27.214 studio[24845:598977] Can't find bundled java.The folder doesn't exist: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr
2021-01-02 14:28:27.214 studio[24845:598977] Can't find bundled java.The folder doesn't exist: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jdk
```

You can try to reinstall Java.

or else, Try to [reinstall](https://redirector.gvt1.com/edgedl/android/studio/install/4.1.1.0/android-studio-ide-201.6953283-mac.dmg) android Studio and check if it works.

I think the problem is that MacOS is still trying or has failed to verify Android Studio.app. Try opening up your terminal and type in:

`xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /Applications/Android\ Studio.app`

This command makes sure MacOS skips verification for given App, so it should start.

Comment: I reinstalled it several times, but it does not work. Even xattr didn't solve the problem.

Comment: uninstall your JDK and redownload and install it.

Comment: or else, you can also try to delete ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio and retry the above steps

Comment: I did all of that but failed. so I tried the IntelliJ idea, open it successfully.

Comment: I got an error: "No such xattr: com.apple.quarantine" ; does this not work on MacOS mojave?

Comment: Oh, I guess that meant I had already previously removed the extended attributes, and still it wasn't working, so something else is wrong.